# Bizarre behavior with :select in .find()

Tags: jquery

I'm in the process of updating a site that currently uses jQuery 1.3.2 to at least 1.10.2. When I do, the site chokes on commands like this:

```
this.form.find(':select[name="fieldtype"]');
```

This shouldn't work - it should be: `this.form.find('select[name="fieldtype"]');` - without the colon - but it in fact works.

I've found nothing that suggests ':select...' is valid. Is it possible that the colon was simply ignored in jQ 1.3.2?

Comment: Are you saying it works on both jQuery versions, or just the old version?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] please?

Comment: Is jquery.migrate installed?

Comment: No, it works with 1.3.2 but fails with 1.10.2. jquery.migrate was installed with 1.10.2, but it errors with: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: select

Comment: I don't understand, you say the site chokes on it, and then your next sentence is "it shouldn't work, but it does"...so, does the site choke or does it work?

Comment: With jQ 1.3.2 it works. Upgrading to 1.10.2 causes the error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: select

Comment: ah i see what your saying thanks

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

I completely forgot about custom pseudo selectors. If, for legacy purposes you need a newer version of jQuery to treat `:select` like `select`, you can do this:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    select: function (el) {
        return jQuery(el).is('select');
    }
});
```

And now `jQuery(':select')` and `jQuery('select')` are equivalent expressions.

**Explanation**

It appears to be an error with the [`sizzle`](https://sizzlejs.com/) css selector engine used by jquery, so that jquery could select dom elements before `document.querySelectorAll` was a thing (or a widely available thing). jQuery 1.3.2 uses sizzle 0.9.3 (pre version 1!), the next version of jQuery, 1.4.0, uses sizzle 1.0.0, where the bug is not present.

The bug specifically seems to be that proper tags prefixed with a ":" will be interpreted as a tag rather than an invalid pseudo

You can verify sizzle being the culprit:

- Download jquery 1.3.2 and jquery 1.4
- Copy the sizzle 1.0.0 block
  out of 1.4 and replace the sizzle 0.9.3 block in 1.3.2

Your "hybrid 1.3.2" version will now also reject the selector.